# Filter GoogleSheet data based on multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a GoogleSheet structured as follow :

- sheet1 contains data from column A to Z.
- sheet2 is using data from sheet1 (I use arrayformula to import data from the columns that I need + added a few columns to input other data or modify the initial data)
- sheet3 that would filter data from sheet 2 importing data that only matches one of the 3 following conditions : column R contains a number starting with "6" OR containing exactly "380" OR containing the text "SPENDESK" OR "containing the text "AUTOLIQUIDATION"

I understand that the "filter" function could be a great place to start but it seems that the "query" function is the one I should be using here but I struggle with identifying how I can add multiple conditions especially on the same column while still using it as a way to display all the columns from my reference sheet.

[Based on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497959/filter-a-query-with-multiple-conditions) I have tried this so far :
=FILTER(sheet2!A2:Z5,(sheet2!R>6)+(sheet2!R)+...)
=filter('sheet2'!1:500;'sheet2'!R:R isnumber(search("SPENDESK"));'sheet2'!R:R isnumber(search("AUTOLIQUIDATION")))

Thanks !

Comment: `QUERY` is definitely where I would go for this. You have 80% of the work done already in your text above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QUERY` utilizes simple statements, starting with the range you are querying, followed by statements (if any).

`QUERY(Sheet2!A:Z)` will simple display all results. However adding conditionals will filter that down.

`QUERY(Sheet2!A:Z, "SELECT * WHERE R STARTS WITH '6' OR R = 380 OR R CONTAINS 'SPENDESK' OR  R CONTAINS 'AUTOLIQUIDATION'")`

You can do additional options as desired. Take a look at [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

Keep note of how your cells are formatted, as if they are text (considering you have numbers and text in column R) then the **380** will need to be wrapped in apostrophes to indicate it is a string not a number `'380'`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin I wasn't that far but I was missing how select could be used with * ! 
One last thing remaining, I see that you haven't added quotes (') before and after 380. It seems to create an error but before I add them and close the topic can you confirm this was something unintentional on your end ? Thanks

Comment: Yes so it just depends how you have the column formatted. Typically a number can just be set inline with the query without needing quotes. `= 380` Whereas having them wrapped indicate it is a string value. It gets a little dynamic as the condition `STARTS WITH` will work as a number or string regardless of formatting, but `=` means exactly, so that will take the role of string vs number depending on the formatting of the source. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ultimately if you don't need to do any calculations from this query than I would just format column R as Plain Text and wrap everything in quotes. `'6'` `'380'`.

Comment: Or another option is to use `R LIKE 380` (with or without quotes) which will still only return exact matches since you are not searching wildcards in a string (`R LIKE '%380%`). I know this is a lot of information, there is just a lot of ways to retrieve the same information that are designed for specific needs. Technically `LIKE` is not designed for this specific use but can be used and changes the operation from being an exact match of a number / string to being a number **OR** a string.

Answer (score 0):

To filter data in Sheet3, you can use the `QUERY` function in Google Sheets.

```
=QUERY(sheet2!A2:Z, "SELECT * WHERE (R LIKE '6%') OR (R LIKE '380') OR (R CONTAINS 'SPENDESK') OR (R CONTAINS 'AUTOLIQUIDATION')")
```

Column R of Sheet2 is set as 'Plain Text'.

**Sample sheet1 image**
[image: Sample sheet1 image]

**Sample sheet3 image**
[image: Sample sheet3 image]

Comment: Super useful ! Thanks !